# CSS Z-index declarations for SuperFish Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index, superfish

I am having a problem with z-indexing on a website I am maintaining. It appears to be caused by z-indexing in the SuperFish Menu and a div. However, no matter where I put the position:relative/absolute & z-index: 99999 declarations, the menu is still getting stuck behind the third panel on the right.

To see this problem, you need to hover over Practice Areas, Then Real Estate. You will notice the sub-menu getting stuck behind the panel.

It's driving me nuts trying to figure this out.

The website is: `http://174.120.240.5/~rushmars/`

Comment: These may help understanding what causes the problem:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context  
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements

Comment: Should I be applying it to the root or further up? I've tried applying the rules to nearly every child in the sf-menu. Nothing seems to work. I'll put the sf-menu items at z-index 99999 and the div to, say, 1 and it doesn't seem to change the stacking order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much positioned elements. Lets look at the whole thing in a tree.

- body - `position: relative`

  - #main

    - header - `position: relative; z-index: 99`
    - .primary_content_tail - `position: relative; z-index: 9300`
  - footer

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) says

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element which is [...] positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than "auto"

So we have two stacking contexts so the menu which is in the header will always be behind the content. Try to set z-indeces to auto (inline). Now we have

- body - `position: relative`

  - #main

    - header - `position: relative; z-index: auto`
    - .primary_content_tail - `position: relative; z-index: auto`
  - footer

And it works as expected in Chrome Canary and Firefox Aurora. If you need the initial z-indeces you might need to create a new layer (stacking context) for the menu.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed this problem. I was not aware the problem could be caused by the positioning even though you need that declaration for z-indexing.